# Generating code into an existing C# class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I am working on a project that makes programming on visual studio easier for non-experienced programmers who need to create some specific programs.To do this i want to take advantage of code-generation.I am providing these users with a project template that provides them with a base structure and files.They can then add the files and code they need for their program.For one of the classes they need to add in the project, i provide them with a configuration wizard which generates the code according to what they select on the wizard;let's call this class Foo.cs.

```
//this class was generated by a wizard
class Foo
 {
      string Name;
      string adress;
      string country;
 }
```

After this class is generated i want to instantiate an object of it in a file that already exists in the project,let's call this second class FooManager.cs.

```
class FooManager
    {
        //This is the line i want to add to the class
        Foo addedFoo = new Foo();
        FooManager()
         {
         }

        //the class may also contain some other code
     }
```

My question is,is it possible to automatically generate code into an existing file?
If i am to use T4 Text Templates to add code to the existing file,i have to copy the code that already exists in the file probably into some buffer,add the code that i want to add and rewrite it back to the file,can somebody please tell me the best way to do this?Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not using partial classes?

Comment: I'd like to leave partial classes as the final option because the users are not experienced and i don't want to start 'breaking-down' the file unless it's very necessary.Thanks though..

Comment: @techRooky That's precisely what partial classes are for.

Comment: So there is absolutely no other way of doing this apart from using partial classes?Cause i really want it to be my last resort.I've used partial classes to extend almost all the other classes and was hoping to avoid it in this one. @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Look into [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform) - it will let you actually deal AST rather than parsing code yourself... (I think there are way too many approaches to solve you problem... so unlikely to get small concrete answer here).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i'll have to look into that,never used it before..thanks